# Good PHP mock framework

Tags: php, frameworks, mocking

Is there a good standalone mock framework for PHP? Currently I am using Simpletest framework for unit testing. I like the framework, but I dont like how you create and setup a mock in it. I then tried PHPMock, I like how it can be used, but it I encountered some bugs that get annoying over time ... Or would it be best to switch over to PHPUnit for unit testing and mocking?

What I would really like is something easy and yet powerful like the Moq framework for C# in PHP (no generics, lambdas etc. of course ;) ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I've not implemented a mock framework myself, I was impressed with [Mockery](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/392-The-Mockery-An-Independent-Mock-Object-and-Stub-Framework-for-PHP5.html).

Its a completely independent mock and stub framework that you should be able to integrate easily with any existing framework or just into your existing code base.

Comment: Do you know if this is a progressed version of PHPMock? On the same blog there exists a post about PHPMock (http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/320-PHPMock-Independent-Mock-ObjectStub-Framework.html) but Mockery is at least two years newer.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this was written from scratch. It may employ ideas PHPMock, but I'm pretty certain that the similarities end there.

Comment: when you are already at it, try `Codeception` (which does extend `PHPUnit`, to enable BDD) in combination with the `Mockery` framework

Answer (score 3):

I would go for PHPUnit.

- I have positive experiences with it,
- it is supported in IDEs (Zend studio, NetBeans),
- and Zend framework (Doctrine ORM, etc.) developers use it also.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [FBMock](https://github.com/facebook/FBMock)

It's a very straightforward and simple mocking framework that is used extensively in Facebook's large PHP codebase.